# Terraform Dynamic Block for Firewall log config

Tags: module, terraform

Thanks for the help and time spent in advance.

I am trying to create terraform module for AWS network firewall configuration.

The below is my code:

```
  firewall_arn = var.firewall_arn
  logging_configuration {
    dynamic "config" {
      for_each = var.log_destination_configs  
      content {  
        log_destination {
          bucketName      = lookup(config.value, "bucketName", null)
          prefix          = lookup(config.value, "prefix", null)  
          logGroup        = lookup(config.value, "logGroup", null)
          deliveryStream  = lookup(config.value, "deliveryStream", null)  
        }
        log_destination_type = lookup(config.value, "log_destination_type", null)
        log_type             = lookup(config.value, "log_type", null)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I tried to compile, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on ../../main.tf line 4, in resource "aws_networkfirewall_logging_configuration" "default":
   4:     dynamic "config" {

Blocks of type "config" are not expected here.
}
```

Is it because I'm declaring the block within logging_configuration and that is not allowed?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [logging_configuration argument documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/networkfirewall_logging_configuration#logging-configuration), the nested block is named `log_destination_config` and not `config`. That is why the error message states that a block `config` is not expected within that block. If you update the block name and lambda scope variables accordingly:

```
logging_configuration {
  dynamic "log_destination_config" {
    for_each = var.log_destination_configs

    content {  
      log_destination {
        bucketName      = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "bucketName", null)
        prefix          = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "prefix", null)  
        logGroup        = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "logGroup", null)
        deliveryStream  = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "deliveryStream", null)  
      }
      log_destination_type = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "log_destination_type", null)
      log_type             = lookup(log_destination_config.value, "log_type", null)
    }
  }
}
```

then that should resolve the issue around your error message.